# Getting SQL to filter rows from a join, on a dynamic property

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question, so I'm going to demonstrate what I'm trying to do with an example.  I'm using Python SQLAlchemy, but an answer in plain old SQL would be fine, just so I could understand the query.

I have two tables (this is a contrived example), that look something like this:

```
Table: Users
id | username
1  | john
2  | bob 
3  | mary
4  | sally    

Table: Updates
id | date  | message | user_id
1  | 11-14 | m3      | 1 
2  | 11-13 | m2      | 1 
3  | 11-12 | m1      | 1 
4  | 11-13 | n2      | 2 
5  | 11-12 | n1      | 2 
6  | 11-12 | o1      | 3
```

The "updates" table is populated daily, via a script, but each user may not have an update for that day.  I'm trying to figure out how I can query both tables to pull the "latest" update for each user.  For example, I'd want my output to look something like the following:

```
username | date  | message
john     | 11-14 | m3
bob      | 11-13 | n2
mary     | 11-12 | o1
sally    |       |
```

I get tripped up, because the "date" value won't be the same for each user, so I can't match that column against a static value.

From a high level, I picture the SQLAlchemy looking something like this:

```
Updates.query.join(Users).filter((Users.id == Updates.user_id) & (Updates.date == LATEST_DATE_IN_UPDATES_BY_USER)).all()
```

Where the "LATEST_DATE_IN_UPDATES_BY_USER" represents the most recent row in the update table, for that user.  I'm not sure how to get that behavior, though.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT Us.username, Up.Date, Up.Message
FROM USERS Us
    LEFT JOIN UPDATES Up on Us.id = Up.user_id
        AND Up.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM UPDATES u WHERE u.user_id = Up.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlalchemy, the simple solution (similar to the answer from @radu-gheorghiu) would be:

```
sq = (
    session
    .query(Update.user_id, func.max(Update.date).label("max_date"))
    .group_by(Update.user_id)
).subquery("subq")

q = (
    session
    .query(User.username, Update.date, Update.message)
    .outerjoin(sq, User.id == sq.c.user_id)
    .outerjoin(Update, and_(User.id == Update.user_id, Update.date == sq.c.max_date))
)
```

And if your database supports `RANK` functions, you can use:

```
expr = func.rank().over(partition_by=Update.user_id, order_by=Update.date.desc()).label("rank")
# need subquery because cannot use RANK in the WHERE part directly
sq = session.query(Update, expr).subquery("subq")
q = (
    session
    .query(User.username, Update.date, Update.message)
    .select_entity_from(sq)
    .join(User)
    .filter(sq.c.rank == 1)
)
```